# Twig access an Alpine object in its path generation

Tags: twig, alpine.js

I just started to use Alpine and Symfony together.

In one of the templates, I have the following codes:

```
<script>
    function getRandomBook() {
        return {
            book: null,
            refreshBook() {
                this.book=null;
                fetch('https://api/books/random')
                    .then((res)=>res.json())
                    .then((data)=>{
                        this.book=data.data[0];
                    });
            }
        };
    }
</script>
...
        <a href="{{ path('book_detail', {'bookid': book.bookid}) }}">....
        </a>
...
```

`book_detail` is a route defined in my Symfony `routes.yaml`. It shall take in a `bookid` and when clicked, goes to the detail page of that book.

My current problem is: `book` is not passed to the template; instead, it SHOULD be populated by the scripts. So the rendering of the page shows me a twig error: `book is not defined`.

I want my Twig `{{}}` to be able to access this JS-populated object.

I can do a tricky way like this:

```
<a x-bind:href="'{{ path('book_detail', {'bookid': 'dummy'}) }}'.replace('dummy', book.bookid)">
```

But I want to know if it can be done better.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: Either calculate the paths while rendering the template and place them in a custom `data-X` attribute, e.g. `data-route` or use something like [`FOSJsRoutingBundle`](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle)

Comment: I will take a look at this `FOS...Bundle`. Thanks @DarkBee

Answer (score -1):

I would do it like this:

```js
function getRandomBook() {

        return {

            basePath: "{{ path('book_detail') }}",
            fullUrl: "",
            book: null,

            refreshBook() {

                this.book = null;

                fetch('https://api/books/random')
                    .then((res)=>res.json())
                    .then((data)=>{
                        this.book=data.data[0];  // if needed
                        this.fullUrl = this.basePath + "?bookid=" + data.data[0].id;
                    });
            }
        };
    }
```

then:

```html
<a x-bind:href="fullUrl"> 
</a>
```

#### A clarification:

- If you are trying to change the *bookid* parameter at the Twig level in the face of an AJAX call, you can't, since the Twig template is processed on the server, while *book.bookid* exists when you are already in the browser.
  Otherwise you would have to generate all the HTML for the *<a>* tag on the server and then update it via Javascript.
- The method you used with *replace()* is valid but a bit "crude".
  Since you are using Alpine, you can adopt a solution in line with the one I suggested and which appears more elegant: the base URL of the route is produced by Twig and frozen in an Alpine (Javascript) variable as a string, then at each AJAX call another variable linked to the *href* is updated and contains the base URL with the parameter received

Comment: The route `book_details` requires a parameter `book_id` as illustrated by OP

Comment: @DarkBee If you read the code carefully you can see that the parameter is handled dynamically. TaylorR doesn't explain how the route is defined, if pretty-urls are used, the code needs to be adapted accordingly, the important thing was to show how to handle the situation on the Alpine side. If I'm missing something, please explain further.

Comment: The fact that twig is rendered serverside and can't interact with client interactions? See my comments and the close vote

Comment: Clear, but with javascript (in this case AlpineJs) you can dynamically modify the DOM. Among other things, the author indicates that his method works, but he would like something more elegant

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply above. I am aware of the Server-side and Client-side render. Twig renders first, and that is why it is not aware of a client-side var (`book`) in this case.